How to debug a React application running on a virtual machine from your main machine?
I am currently developing a web application using React and ExpressJS. This application is located on a virtual machine that acts as a server to host the application. I am using VMware to run my virtual machine on my own machine.
I am using the Webstorm IDE to develop the application and I have managed to set up backend debugging using a configuration "Attach to NodeJs/Chrome". However, I am unable to set up front-end debugging despite the solutions I have tested.
To set up front-end debugging, I tried to set up a "JavaScript debug" configuration, but no matter what parameters I enter in this configuration, my IDE tries to connect to "localhost:[random_port]" when it should be trying to connect to the IP address of my virtual machine.
Here is the message that appears when I try to launch front-end debugging:
"Waiting for connection to localhost:35675. Please ensure that the browser was started successfully with remote debugging port opened. Port cannot be opened if Chrome having the same User Data Directory is already launched."
